# file system requirements for postgresql and/or mysql

Tags: mysql, filesystems, postgresql

I'm currently tasked with making postgresql run in kubernetes in azure using a `azureFile` for storage.

There are numerous posts and github issues stating that postgresql cannot run with azureFile. The biggest show stopper is the permissions requirement for the data directory (for which there are some workarounds)

But even if I work around the permissions problem there's another - hard links.
Some github issues and docs (e.g. [this](https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container/issues/286#issuecomment-410167258), [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/70606) and [this](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_azure_file.html)) state that postgresql needs to be able to create hard links and we can see that from the error log in the fist link above.

[Azure docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/features-not-supported-by-the-azure-file-service) clearly state that hard links are not supported. I've been looking for official postgresql documentation on file system requirements, but I'm not finding any.

Can someone point me to official documentation where it's stated that hard links are required?

I also have to look at mysql as an alternative, but [this](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_azure_file.html) suggest I'll be having the same issues.

**EDIT**:
A tool which tests postgresql/mysql required file system features would also be very helpful, but I'm not finding any.

Comment: Is Azure Files a hard requirement? Can't you use [Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/)? That would be much easier, and probably more cost effective

Comment: it is currently, but im trying to argue against it, that why i need something more official

Comment: Why doe you need "containers"?

Comment: @RickJames its a client requirement which im trying to argue